# How to specify stride for array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

For example, how to access the array elements with odd index:

```
@a=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
print "@a[1..7 with step 2]";
```

The result I want is:
`1 3 5 7`

Comment: `map { $_ * 2 } 0..$#a/2` (as shown in the linked answer) should be better than `grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } 0..$#a` (as shown by the answers below) since it creates half as many scalars.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of your pseudo-code, here is one option using array slices and `grep`:

```
my @a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
print @a[ grep { ($_ - 1) % 2 } 0 .. $#a ];
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep`ing in an *array slice*:

```
my @a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
print join " ", @a[ grep { ! ($_ % 2) } 0 .. $#a ];
```